# ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')) vector = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)

Tags: python, langchain

I am following the quickstart of Langchain with local models, while doing Retrieval Chain part, I found that FAISS code can't connect.
This is my code:

```
from langchain_community.llms 
import Ollamafrom langchain_core.prompts 
import ChatPromptTemplatefrom langchain_core.output_parsers 
import StrOutputParserfrom langchain_community.document_loaders 
import WebBaseLoaderfrom langchain_community.embeddings 
import OllamaEmbeddingsfrom langchain_community.vectorstores 
import FAISSfrom langchain_community.vectorstores 
import Chromafrom langchain.text_splitter 
import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitterfrom langchain.chains.combine_documents 
import create_stuff_documents_chainfrom langchain.chains 
import create_retrieval_chain
```

```
#Load documentloader = WebBaseLoader("https://docs.smith.langchain.com/overview")docs = loader.load()#Embeddingsembeddings = OllamaEmbeddings()#Documents + embeddings -> get vectorstext_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter()documents = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
```

```
vector = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
```

```
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("""Answer the following question based only on the provided context:
```

```
{context}
```

```
Question: {input}""")
```

```
llm = Ollama(model="mistral")#llm + promptsdocument_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)#vectors + llm + promptsretriever = vector.as_retriever()retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, document_chain)
```

```
response = retrieval_chain.invoke({"input": "how can langsmith help with testing?"})print(response["answer"])`
```

And this is the error that show, I really new in this and can't realize what is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 461, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 470, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 461, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 157, in _process_emb_response
    res = requests.post(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pikachu/Desktop/LangChain/RetrievalChain.py", line 21, in <module>
    vector = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 778, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 736, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 275, in add_texts
    embeddings = self._embedding_function.embed_documents(texts)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 204, in embed_documents
    embeddings = self._embed(instruction_pairs)
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 192, in _embed
    return [self._process_emb_response(prompt) for prompt in iter_]
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 192, in <listcomp>
    return [self._process_emb_response(prompt) for prompt in iter_]
  File "/home/pikachu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 163, in _process_emb_response
    raise ValueError(f"Error raised by inference endpoint: {e}")
ValueError: Error raised by inference endpoint: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I am running it on ubuntu 22.04.

Explain what happened and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug as [In the issue here](https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/2198). To fix it, update Ollama using

- `curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh` | sh
- Or by downloading the ollama binary  `sudo curl -L https://ollama.com/download/ollama-linux-amd64 -o /usr/bin/ollama sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/ollama`,

Finally reload systemd and restart Ollama:

- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl restart ollama`